# Convert Aes.Key to SecureString in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, arrays, securestring

How do I convert Aes.Key to a secureString ? I am doing a byte[] -> string -> securestring. I am facing a different problem. 
When converting the key, in byte[], to string and back to byte[] I get a different byte[]. What is the problem with the code ?

```
Aes aes = Aes.Create();
aes.GenerateIV();
aes.GenerateKey();

byte[] byteKey1 = aes.Key; 

string sKey = Encoding.UniCode.GetString(byteKey);
byte[] byteKey2= Encoding.UniCode.GetBytes(sKey);
```

"byteKey1" and "byteKey2" are sometimes different. They are equal if I use Encoding.Default but that has problems when different machines have different default encoding.

How do I convert the Key in byte[] to SecureString and back to byte[] ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never use text encoding (e.g., Unicode or ASCII) on binary data like a cryptographic key or ciphertext.  Encoding is intended for textual representations, and the implementation can change the binary contents as permitted by the encoding.

Instead, use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert binary text into a form that can be encoded in a textual format.

The following code will illustrate `byteKey2` and `byteKey` will be identical.

```
string sKey = Convert.ToBase64String(byteKey);
byte[] byteKey2= Convert.FromBase64String(sKey);
bool equal = byteKey.SequenceEqual(byteKey2); // will be true
```